# Reference Request: Differential Graded Hopf Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, hopf-algebras

To prepare an upcoming seminar talk I’m trying to find introductory texts on differential graded Hopf algebras (over a field $k$).

My knowledge of Hopf algebras encompasses roughly the first 5 chapters of Sweedler’s book.
I also have a rough idea of how to define dg-Hopf algebras, namely by the same diagrams as an ordinary Hopf algebra but with dg-vector spaces instead of just vector spaces (i.e. as “Hopf objects” in the monoidal category of dg-vector spaces).
I’m thus looking for references that do the following:

- Providing an explicit definition of dg-Hopf algebras and showing their fundamental properties.
- Giving (basic) examples for dg-Hopf algebras.
- Explaining the differences and similarities between ordinary Hopf-algebras and dg-Hopf algebras.
- (Giving me a way to check my thoughts and suspicions.)

I was originally given [1] and [2] as references (the last of which is also given on the nlab) but [1] only really deals with ordinary Hopf algebras and [2] doesn’t seem to provide introductory material.
I already found [3], which provides some background on dg-algebras, -coalgebras and -Lie algebras, but only little on dg-bialgebras and nothing on dg-Hopf algebras.

[1]: Loday, *Cyclic Homology*, Appendix A
[2]: Quillen, *Rational Homotopy Theory*, Appendix B
[3]: Félix, Halperin, Thomas, *Rational Homotopy Theory*, Chapters 3,21

Comment: Were you successful in finding an introductory reference? If so, what was it?

Comment: @AviSteiner, no, sadly not.

Comment: Any chance you still have the notes from the seminar talk you gave?

Comment: @AviSteiner The handout of the talk is available online at https://gitlab.com/cionx/topology-seminar-hopf-algebras-ss19 (both the LaTeX code and a compiled pdf version).

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a reference better than "wikipedia definition of Hopf algebra in a braided category" and it specialization to the braiding $v\otimes w\mapsto (-1)^{|v||w|}w\otimes v$. But I can give you the first elementary and nontrivial example of d.g. Hopf algebra that is not a Hopf algebra in the usual sense:

Fix a field of characteristic not 2 and $H=k[x]/x^2$. Then $H$ is not a Hopf algebra, because it is commutative and has nontrivial nilpotent elements. On the other hand, it is a d.g. Hopf algebra with $|1|=0$, $|x|=1$ and $d(x)=1$, simply defining 
$$\Delta(x)=x\otimes 1 +1\otimes x$$

The reason is that, if you define $\Delta$ as above, the way you extend it to $k[x]$ in the d.g. setting is considering the algebra structure in $k[x]\otimes k[x]$ given by 
$$(x^n\otimes x^m)\cdot (x^i\otimes x^j)=(-1)^{im}x^{n+1}\otimes x^{n+j}$$
With this structure, the element $x^2$ mapsto
$$(x\otimes 1+1\otimes x) ^2 =x^2\otimes 1+x\otimes x -x\otimes x+1\otimes x^2=x^2\otimes 1+1\otimes x^2$$
(and not to $x^2\otimes 1+2x\otimes x+1\otimes x^2$)
So, the "super sign" makes the job so that the ideal $(x^2)$ is also a coideal, and hence $\Delta:k[x]/x^2\to k[x]/x^2\otimes k[x]/x^2$ is a well-defined algebra map, when considering $k[x]/x^2\otimes k[x]/x^2$ as algebra using the Koszul signs.

Comment: I don’t see how $d(x) = 1$ is supposed to work: Then $1 \in k[x]/x^2$ is a boundary but $1 \in k$ is not, so the counit $\varepsilon \colon k[x]/x^2 \to k$ cannot be a morphism of dg-algebras. I think it should be $d(x) = 0$, so that we get the dg-symmetric algebra on a one-dimensional dg-vector space concentrated in degree 1 (if I understand this correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start from [Peter Schauenburg's *Differential-Graded Hopf Algebras and Quantum Group Differential Calculi*](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X01238/1-s2.0-S0021869396900642/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDp9IWJRkTaVkxcGEUfqoFMDkq%2Bj0PmL30VzlfAZHrcSgIhAL7tQVb8kim%2FEPj2sekIQO8VEoKgn8mOz1WSwqZbEjz4KuMDCJH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQAhoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgyHU4kUGI1auI2%2FjwIqtwPzlDzxACiAo2S%2BuoHnl0HQR71cc4CiNH411namEK1UWM9FRQs%2Fb3GRuSDBn5GCosbbdIFsWBr2NK5xQiIZtGKRmaI%2FIahO1WoNJLYVeK1a%2Bi3jkPvMMIZCaOnn3vHil%2FuSn6oOIJH%2B8HLf8skSdTbqruDDafiYX7BSiaAf1xeq1O57X6GQFPjfZr%2FvISIqlUnSn354jGXQKK291bjG6vSi1qqGa2u%2BEMiM91K1VDMy5DsiEOJnK3Sy0GzLPbXQ4fwYO7fPbZFvg%2FsYDjFIDW53COZsu1wCgK7qUmSk%2B5AeNjxXjGElAydJR9%2BUhrQzGo0Bayv5mAvcORy7cXQo8ptwHQ8jfo83OH3SuhfwOn2F5IbQ9a2q8r4Hq6xYHqk8tnf86eYufKNbnLCs0aTH5CM0okibZ1DywfcjKxbqYSXpkwslA8bKymfACAR96fxk4TDTJS%2FamltRAnBqYJxyY0eCrpLc7PuL0EEZzXxD3E816lqR8geR%2BPd5tcS%2FXPXrrhbCJAaHhr56%2BfPK2KP8tITfpklG%2B62TmBMojwGPCwUeoAccvSQpJPM1rhS%2FdbC87h3u%2FnJmGpH9MIrJkOcFOrMBAq4pZL8uWooKrkKGchnYmoy40tVxSxYOLXgIueqMypFi%2Bj7LDGSXh1080VPS8rsxtg4m6%2FPg0JZ3NxlSHLkrJrHJKMI4AenhjLobnk2BbCzBAEGEcb%2ByPQ%2FRZlXlQKI4PfMpTarqeptrwkqDWipNIyR5dSVBJcK%2FS4DveW2nDKSy7Z2P%2FdJ47MExAsMB6qItlAEZ7ftNBoHxp7K8rJTUgowTGd69nQsrZ3jv0CrE3XoqzVo%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTYXDPWJJUK&Expires=1558461762&Signature=ofK5jX4PUgrbjYXEQl8Eg%2F%2FgfuA%3D&hash=0e0fae98df44e36fb0b13419e53eacf464da9d10399372b4d9d936b746ce14e2&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021869396900642&tid=spdf-73c65464-362f-4073-8a43-583a59539517&sid=e9aa9e7a2848854ee60a4f294d5447e9592dgxrqb&type=client). He is used to be pretty clear, at least for those who like category theory. The references therein may be a further source.